# How does parse-server create long-lived tokens for Facebook login?

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, parse-server

Ive been studying Parse server and how it works with Facebook authentication and there is something I do not quite follow.

According to the Facebook Graph API documentation, to create a long-lived token (60 days), the server needs to call the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing

I checked the parse-server github code and I cannot find anywhere in the code where it makes the graph API request to the "/oauth" endpoint or passes the "fb_exchange_token" query parameter as in the picture.

Is parse-server getting long-lived tokens via some older Facebook Graph API pattern or am I missing something? Thanks!

Example GET request from FB docs:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

[Example GET request from FB Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKKM2.png)

Comment: Do you have evidence Parse is *getting* long lived tokens? I don't see a reason it'd need to for the built-in authentication functionality - short-lived ones would be just fine.

Comment: Good question. My evidence is I saw the expiration dates on the access_tokens when I authenticated through FB on parse-server and they were 60 days.

Comment: Tokens acquired using the server-side login flow used to be extended by default. (Currently can’t find where that was mentioned in the docs; not sure if still the case with all the current changes though.)

Comment: @CBroe that makes a whole lot of sense and lines up with my current suspicion: that it is some default or pattern that used to be documented, but is no longer documented. Thanks a bunch.